# Issue with meta tags

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

I know there are many ways to put keywords into a website. I am in my index.php and this is what I see

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?=$keywords?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?=description?>">
```

Where do I put my keywords in? Do I remove the `?=$` and the second?

Thank you all.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Your keywords should be in the PHP variable `$keywords`, e.g.

```
<?php 

$keywords = "php html meta-tags";
$description = "Issue with meta tags";

?>

<meta name="keywords" content="<?= $keywords ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?= $description ?>">
```

You were also missing a `$` in the description line.

The use of `<?=` requires that you have the PHP short_open_tags option enabled. If you don't have that option, write:

```
<?php echo $keywords; ?>
```

Comment: Technically this answers the question, but is the keywords meta tag even used anymore? http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html - I trust Barmar's opinion on this

Comment: I know practically nothing about SEO, so I won't express an opinion on whether these tags are useful or not.

Comment: I don't really research it myself either, but a while back our front end guys stopped putting the keywords meta in headers making the same claim that article says. Anyone else know something we don't?

Comment: no, i also do not know many things about SEO, but i really was suprised by your (Kai Qing) comment relating to the keyword meta-tag! Thank you very much! now i can stop thinking about good keywords for my sites :-D

Comment: Note that the Google document _does_ say that they sometimes use the `description` meta tag. Anyway, there isn't really anything in this question or answer that's specific to keywords or meta tags, it just shows how to get PHP variables into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

just change your code to

```
<?php

 // some PHP-code, e.g. defining $keywords and $description

?>

<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
```

Comment: Thank you all. What is the purpose of the ?=$?